# Moving NSPanel by background with some NSViews on it

Tags: cocoa, nspanel

I have a `NSPanel`. When the panel is empty, is moves well with holding and dragging it's background. However, If I put something on it, the area covered by new view won't be draggable anymore. As an example, I could put a `NSImageView` fills the panel fully. And the panel do not being dragged anymore. However I want to make this draggable even user holding on the image view. What should I do to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subclass your `NSImageView` and implement [`- (BOOL)mouseDownCanMoveWindow`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/mouseDownCanMoveWindow) to return `YES`. Then you'll be able to drag the window wherever you click.

Comment: I didn't tested this solution yet, but it seems to work. Thanks!